# What package ID used for link in PlayMarket when using gradle?

Tags: android, google-play, package

I see that Play Market we have links to app looking that way:

play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=**com.DevName.AppName**

But I developing app with gradle. When My app running on the device - in "running apps" it has id "com.DevName.AppName.app"

So my question is How will the link to the application look in my case? It is necessary for the normal operation "Rate Us" button.
And I need it before loading apk to PlayMarket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I uploaded app to Google Play. So if You have same questions: app package ID with .app postfix when You use Gradle in Intellij Idea. Just like com.devname.appname.app.